# 'open file' dialog in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How do I get an OpenFileDialog in ASP.NET without using the FileUpload control?

Comment: what do you want to do with the OpenFile dialog ?

Answer (score 2):

If the Silverlight avenue is an option, the Silverlight [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415(VS.95).aspx) might be worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Note that ASP.NET merely renders the HTML file input, and the browser handles the rest.  If you want different behavior, you'll need to do something on the client side, like JavaScript, Flash, etc.

I would start with [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), which uses jQuery and Flash.