# How to programmatically open an OpenFileDialog box in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the following code to open an Open FileDialog:

```
OpenFile("D:\\");
```

I get "Access denied".

How might I open an OpenFileDialog window an a web application?

Comment: I want if i am clicking on a button than OpenFileDialog window should open.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['open file' dialog in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850025/open-file-dialog-in-asp-net)

Comment: Do you need open a dialogue for a file which is located on client or server?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should tell us more about what you are trying to achieve. Any call to common dialogues from the server side will be (try to be) performed on the server. To provide the user with the facility to eq. choose and upload file, you need to use other methods that will be invoked on client side (JScript, Flash, Silverlight...).